# Send email with sharepoint

Tags: development

I'm trying to send an email using c# sharepoint library. Though I'm getting an error that reads...

```
Error in test: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The code I'm executing is as follows. It's fairly simple, though I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
                string SPSite = "spsite";                           
                using(SPSite objSite = new SPSite(SPSite))
                {
                    using(SPWeb oweb = objSite.OpenWeb())
                    {

                        SPUtility.SendEmail(oweb, false, false, "email@email.com", "Title test", "this is the body");
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you check if your mail server is good. 
`bool blnIsEmailServerSet = SPUtility.IsEmailServerSet(web);`

An alternate way to get this done:
http://emailfromsharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/04/send-email-from-sharepoint.html